# Show exit intent popup on back button pression or url bar change

Tags: javascript

i have created this exit intent popup that now appear when user move mouse from the website area. i want to change it on:

- when user click on back button in browser
- and when try to change the url address

```
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      document.addEventListener('mouseout', (event) => {
        // Utilizziamo sessionstorage per memorizzare la visita dell'utente
        var FirstVisit = sessionStorage.getItem('fired');
        // Condizione della prima visita
        if (FirstVisit !== '1')
          if (!event.toElement && !event.relatedTarget)
            if (!app.session.user) {
              setTimeout(() => {
                Dontleave();
              }, 1000);
              // La prima visita segna la chiusura della sessione
              sessionStorage.setItem('fired', '1');
```

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

one idea is to play with browser history and add a state where a message is display to user

```
history.replaceState(null, document.title, location.pathname + '#!/hereiam');
history.pushState(null, document.title, location.pathname);

window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
    if(location.hash === '#!/hereiam') {
        history.replaceState(null, document.title, location.pathname);
        alert('win');
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: but this doesn't have a good experience if a user simply go back but remain into the same site

Comment: you are right in the if you have to replace the history with the true go back location
`history.replaceState(null, document.title, location.pathname);`